# How to repeatedly append strings

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, append, repeat

Hello I am a new programmer, I am looking to repeatedly append strings in a dictionary, at least 3 times.

For example:

input:

```
{Words:['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
```

output:

```
{Words:['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye','hi', 'bye', 'goodbye','hi', 'bye', 'goodbye','hi', 'bye', 'goodbye','hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
```

What I have tried is:

```
d = {'Words':['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
new_d = {}
for key in d:
    new_d[key] = []
    for element in d[key]:
        new_d[key] += [element]*10

print new_d
```

But I get this output:

```
{'Words':['hi','hi','hi','hi','hi', 'bye','bye','bye','bye','bye','bye', 'goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye','goodbye']}
```

The above is not the output I am looking for...

Answer (score 4):

Just multiply it:

```
>>> ['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']*3
['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']
```

So in your context, it would be something like this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = v*3
```

Alternatively, you can also use a function, although a bit more complicated:

```
def multiply(l, n):
    length = len(l)
    new = []
    for _ in range(n):
        for i in range(length):
                new.append(l[i])
     return new
```

Result:

```
>>> l = ['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']
>>> multiply(l, 2)
['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']
```

Here's how you can use the function:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = multiply(v)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello, what is k and v?

Comment: Common shorthands for "key" and "value"

Comment: Hi! We're looping through the key-value pair in the dictionary. `k` is the current key, and `v` is the current value :)

Comment: ahh I see, okay let me try to implement this.

Comment: hello, I am getting the correct list output... but I am not getting the key and dictionary... I am just getting the list.

Comment: No need to start each of your message with hello. Are you using the second method?

Comment: first one I am using... oh wait I think I got. let me try something.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for this:

```
>>> dct = {'Words':['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
>>> {k:v*5 for k,v in dct.items()}
{'Words': ['hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye', 'hi', 'bye', 'goodbye']}
>>>
```

In case you want it, here is a reference on [`dict.items`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).